# Providing vernacular support on saving & retrieving entities in existing APIs

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, elasticsearch, system-design

**Current functionality :**

`/get/address/` :   get all saved address for a user

`/update/address/{address_id}` : update existing address.

`/search/address/{query}` : search the address in ElasticSearch based on the query.

Tech stack :-

```
MySQL         - to persist all addresses
ElasticSearch - to index addresses, so that we can search them fast.
Spring-boot.  - backend framework.
```

Currently we store everything in english language in **MySQL** and **ElasticSearch**.

Going ahead, we need to support the vernacular(multiple languages) addresses, in which user can save the address in multiple regional languages and search the address as well in the same regional language.

> What changes we need to do to at API or DB/ES level to incorporate
> this vernacular support in the APIs ?

Comment: In MySQL, use `CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4` everywhere.

Comment: @RickJames, that's it. Understood changing character set will change the max number of bytes a char takes to store, which is 4 byte. But can we save the data in raw format(any language), in DB/elastic for update and search cases. And what about the get calls, will the response will be same as the one we have changed without messing up the encoding formats

Comment: If you currently have data stored in, say "latin1", it needs to be converted somehow.  In MySQL, you must correctly state the "character set" (latin1 / utf8mb4 / etc) based on the _client_.  Then `INSERT` and `SELECT` will convert on the fly to the character set of the column in the table.

Comment: @RickJames Got it. Also if we want to show the static data to user in different languages, would it make sense to store them in DB. Can we keep that in app config files or maybe in Zookeeper, which one would be a better choice here.

Comment: MySQL's "utf8mb4" handles all known languages.  All major OSs and browsers handle "UTF-8".  (Those two "terms" refer to the same encoding.)  I don't see config as being anything more than "get it right, then forget about it."